# Add view- half of the size to the main view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have UIView, I want to add it a view on that view but so it be half of the size of the original View.

I tried :

```
[appDelegate.viewController presentModalViewController:testViewController animated:NO];
```

but itws on **all the screen**.

tried:

```
self.window.frame= CGRectMake(50, 50, 30, 30);
self.frame= CGRectMake(50, 50, 30, 30)
```

I saw there is methods like `presentPopupViewController` but they work on UIViewcontroller.
any ideas to start it on half of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The message `presentModalViewController:animated:` will present the view in a modal fashion, always occupying the entire screen. It will not add the view to your current view.

To do that, use `UIView`'s message `addSubview:`. You can size the subview any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using presentModalViewController:animated: cannot be resized.

To have effect like presentModalViewController:animated: use CATransition like this:

```
 CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
[animation setDuration:0.50];
[animation setTimingFunction:
 [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
```

Now Add view in self.view like this:

```
[self.view addSubView:testViewController.view];
[testViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/4),(self.view.frame.size.height/4),(self.view.frame.size.width*3/4),(self.view.frame.size.height*3/4))];
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have two views one is **mainview** second one is **childview**.

to add childview on mainview

```
 [mainview addSubview:childview];
```

to remove child view from mainview

```
 [childview removeFromSuperview];
```

but if you want some animation than you have to add some extra code for that.

Comment: thank's for the answers SmartWork and @waldrumpus I tried that, adding view's, and it's working with labels,images but I want to add tableViwe to that view and that's I can only do with viewController.